# Which is the oldest version of WebSphere Application Server that supports TLS 1.2?

Tags: linux, ssl, websphere

If I understood correctly, it depends on the JDK and that needs to be at least version 1.7. Also how do you check (in a Linux command line) what JDK the was has, and/or if it can handle TLS 1.2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 is not required. WebSphere has supported TLS1.2 since version 7.0.0.23. Essentially every in-service release of WebSphere supports TLS1.2 (7.0 will go out of service next year)